How to ensure a numeric value from a CSS property that uses var(), calc(), attr(), ...?
I need to get numeric values from an HTMLElement's style. Mostly this is straightforward, even parsing CSS functions. If the value is empty, then I get it from getComputedStyle(). My current problem arises when the property value uses var(), calc(), or attr(). In this case the value is not empty, but I must call getComputedStyle() to get the number(s).
For example (I added the 3 functions suggested by @DiegoD):
const listOfFuncs = ["var","calc","attr","max","min","clamp"];
const lp = "(" // too confusing to read surrounded by parentheses

let value = element.style[propertyName];

if (!value || listOfFuncs.some(v => value.includes(v + lp))
    value = getComputedStyle(element)[propertyName];

My questions are:

Are these 3 the only functions that need this treatment, or am I missing some?
Is there a more efficient/elegant way to process this, other than .some()/.includes() and a hard-coded list of function names + left parenthesis?


Why not always use getComputedStyle only?

@Teemu - Mostly for units and color functions, which get mangled by getComputedStyle().

following the question that was just asked in the comments, I add my 2 cents.. you are fetching those values using "tools" having different meanings.. are you aware of the difference between inline style and css rulesets? I mean the style of an element is far from what's the computed style ... and anyway there are other functions too like min(), max(), clamp() and many others

@DiegoD - yes, min, max, clamp, thanks.  Yes, the element's style has priority over any other style rules applied by class or id or whatever.  There are cases where the user wants specific units or color functions or whatever and they must ensure that the property is specified inline in the element's style attribute.

@SidewaysS I don't think getComputedStyle() "mangles" anything. It works from the actual effective property set in the browser and hands the values back to you in a representation that means the same thing as whatever the actual CSS rules contain. So color strings may come back as rgb() and stuff like that, regardless of how they were represented in the style rule source code.

@Pointy - getComputedStyle() converts everything to px and hsl() and hwb() to the now deprecated rgba() in Chrome and Firefox.

@SidewaysS well my point is that it's not specifically getComputedStyle() that does that. The browser represents the color info in some internal form, and so getting that back uses a single representation in what it returns.

@Pointy - regardless, my user need to be able to control units and color functions and I don't know what else that might get modified by whatever agent when I call getComputedStyle().

It's simply not possible. The internal code that performs the merging of styles canonicalizes everything as it goes. There's no way to get back the original text format.

@Barmar - If you're referring to the way element.style returns modified color functions, I have a special case for that and color-mix() where I call element.getAttribute("style") and parse the attribute string.  element.style preserves non-default units in all my tests, so no issue there.  My question is more about how/when to seek the non-original format than how to get the original string, which is always available via getAttribute() and is easily parsed as a last resort.
